# Second maximum value using qualityMosaic in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to create a composite of Landsat images using the method qualityMosaic in GEE, however, instead of the first maximum value for each pixel, I want the second maximum value for each pixel.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any efficient way to do this, especially if you start looking at the nth highest value, where n starts getting bigger. For second highest, you could get away with getting the highest value, mask it and get the highest of what's left.

```
var highestNdvi = collection.qualityMosaic('ndvi')
var secondHighestNdvi = collection
  .map(function (ndvi) {
    return ndvi.updateMask(ndvi.lt(highestNdvi))
  })
  .qualityMosaic('ndvi') // Find the highest that is left after masking out the highest
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/90822009aea6eb92838617a93296fcd9

Comment: If I needed nth, I'd probably use an array image: https://code.earthengine.google.com/7a8c5226c26d3a0b2b5a35c7a3855344